# how did my laptop lose daylight savings time on power loss?

Tags: windows, power-supply, clock

it was an old laptop that may or may not have dead CMOS battery (at least it had time reset to 0 when I dusted it off). So, it was plugged into power for awhile without the main battery and the clock was correct. Then there was a power outage. When I subsequently turned it on, surprise-surprise, it had one hour off correct time. So the clock apparently kept running during the outage, but daylight savings time info vanished (from disk? where is it stored?)

How come?

Comment: All sorts of odd things happen when the system loses power unexpectedly.  At a guess, the computer hadn't gotten around to updating the hardware clock time when the power was lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
So the clock apparently kept running during the outage, but daylight savings time info vanished (from disk? where is it stored?)
```

Registry, Just enable it and adjust the clock.